# How to initialize const float32x4x4_t (ARM NEON intrinsic, GCC)?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, constants, neon

I can initialize float32x4_t like this:

```
const float32x4x4_t zero = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
```

But this code makes an error **Incompatible types in initializer**:

```
const float32x4x4_t one =
{
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
};
```

float32x4x4_t is 4x4 matrix built as:

```
typedef struct float32x4x4_t
{
    float32x4_t val[4];
}
float32x4x4_t;
```

How can I initialize this const struct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
const float32x4x4_t nameOfVariableHere =
{{
    {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
    {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
    {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},
    {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}
}};
```

The 1st level of parenthesis is for the struct.
The 2nd level is for the array of `float32x4_t`.
The 3rd level is for `float32x4_t` itself.

Comment: Oh my God! I omitted variable name! Sorry for this. I updated my question. And this way makes "error: incompatible types in initialization", "error: extra brace group at end of initializer". Thanks.

Comment: @Eonil: Sorry, I've left the extra comma at the end. Try the update.

Comment: Thanks, but removing last comma is not effective. Same errors.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to initialize a uint16x8_t neon vector. By following your answer I have the following code : uint16x8_t myvect = {{0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF, 0xFFFF}}; but GCC complains with this style of vector initialization. In addition, this document http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0053a/IHI0053A_acle.pdf says that static construction is not defined (12.2.2) ...